# How can i write the urlpattern in a template calling a view function

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

Url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name= 'homepage'),

    url(r'^(?P<single_link>[0-9]+)/$', views.single_link, name='detail'),

    path("reserve_link/<str:print_link>", views.reserve_link, name='reserve_link')
]
```

Views.py

```
def single_link(request, single_link):
    try:
        movie_details = MovieSection.objects.get(pk=single_link)
        movi = MovieDetails.objects.get(movie_section__pk= single_link)
    except MovieSection.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Movie does not exist")
    return render(request, "reviewmovie.html", {"part_ones": movie_details, "movi": movi})

def reserve_link(request, print_link):
    reserve = get_object_or_404(Ticket, movie_details__pk=print_link)

    context = {'reserve': reserve}
    return render(request, "reserve.html", context)
```

Models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    movie_details = models.ForeignKey(MovieDetails, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    movie_section = models.ForeignKey(MovieSection, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    movie_time = models.DateTimeField("Ticket time")
    ticket_link = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

HTML template

```
 <a href="{% url 'reserve_link' %}">Seat Reservation</a>
```

My question is how

1. How will i write a correct urlpattern that will call the reserve_link view function
2. The single_link function generate a details page in the generated page, there should be a page gotten from the details to display some information. How will i write a view function to call that page.
3. How will i write the ink in html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your URLs being;

```py
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name='homepage'),

    url(r'^(?P<single_link>[0-9]+)/$', views.single_link, name='detail'),

    path("reserve_link/<str:print_link>", views.reserve_link, name='reserve_link')
]
```

These would be accessed in HTML using something like;

```html
<a href="{% url 'reserve_link' print_link='my reservation' %}">Seat Reservation</a> 

<a href="{% url 'detail' single_link=3 %}">Detail for link 3</a> 

<a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Home</a>
```

And based on the views you've shared, it looks like your context variables would make your links;

```html
<a href="{% url 'reserve_link' print_link=movi.id %}">Seat Reservation</a> 

<a href="{% url 'detail' single_link=part_ones.id %}">Detail for {{ part_ones }}</a>
```

The `reserve_link` view is going to use the param passed in the query the PK for a `MovieDetails` instance and `single_link` is using it's param as a query for the `MovieSection` PK.

Based on the fact that both of your URL parameters are passed to queries on a ID fields, you should consider changing your URLs to only accept an `int`;

```py
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name='homepage'),

    path("<int:movie_section_id>", views.single_link, name='detail'),

    path("reserve_link/<int:movie_details_id>", views.reserve_link, name='reserve_link')
]
```

The docs for path converters are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters